# "Simulate" command line argument in unit-tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have some functionality, which depends on command line arguments, and different arguments should lead to different results.

I can't directly "simulate" this arguments, since there are some sort of chain dependencies - I need to unit-test some xaml control, which depends on view-model, which depends on certain additional class, which fetches command line arguments using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, and I can't directly impact on this last class to set arguments manually instead of using `GetCommandLineArgs`.

So, I'd like to know, is there any way to make `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` return value I want it to return, for certain unit-test.

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried to use Moq? You can make any method return anything you want.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 I had bad experience trying to mock actual classes, not interfaces. But, some different solution came by, changing the logic i'm actually unit-testing to one, which can be applied moq to.

Comment: You need to abstract `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` behind something you can mock

Comment: Are you saying you can't alter the code that accesses `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`?

Comment: @Wjdavis5 probably means any mock-able method.  Moq can't handle methods that cannot be `override`-d because it can't dynamically generate class or whatever it does under the hood to Mock; so no `sealed` classes or non-`virtual` methods, last I checked (unless Moq has been enhanced).  You'd need something like MS `Fakes` to create stub implementations and "mock" those dependencies (which is not available at VS Professional).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to abstract `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` or what ever is eventually calling it behind something you can mock

```
public interface ICommandLineInterface {
    string[] GetCommandLineArgs();
}
```

Which can eventually be implemented in a concrete class like

```
public class CommandInterface : ICommandLineInterface {
    public string[] GetCommandLineArgs() {
        return Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    }
}
```

And can be Tested using `Moq` and `FluentAssertions`

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Should_Simulate_Command_Line_Argument() {
    // Arrange
    string[] expectedArgs = new[] { "Hello", "World", "Fake", "Args" };
    var mockedCLI = new Mock<ICommandLineInterface>();
    mockedCLI.Setup(m => m.GetCommandLineArgs()).Returns(expectedArgs);
    var target = mockedCLI.Object;

    // Act
    var args = target.GetCommandLineArgs();

    // Assert
    args.Should().NotBeNull();
    args.Should().ContainInOrder(expectedArgs);

}
```

Comment: Very nice idea! +1

Comment: In the end, I did exactly this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with environment variables, why don't we wrap the outside dependencies into one EnvironmentHelper class, then inject the dependencies?

Here is my suggestion:

```
public class EnvironmentHelper
{
    Func<string[]> getEnvironmentCommandLineArgs; 

       // other dependency injections can be placed here

       public EnvironmentHelper(Func<string[]> getEnvironmentCommandLineArgs)
       {
            this.getEnvironmentCommandLineArgs = getEnvironmentCommandLineArgs;
       }

       public string[] GetEnvironmentCommandLineArgs()
       {
            return getEnvironmentCommandLineArgs();
       }
}
```

Here is the Mock method:

```
public static string[] GetFakeEnvironmentCommandLineArgs()
{
    return new string[] { "arg1", "arg2" };
}
```

In your source code:

```
EnvironmentHelper envHelper = new EnvironmentHelper(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs);
string[] myArgs = envHelper.GetEnvironmentCommandLineArgs();
```

In your unit test code:

```
EnvironmentHelper envHelper = new EnvironmentHelper(GetFakeEnvironmentCommandLineArgs);
string[] myArgs = envHelper.GetEnvironmentCommandLineArgs();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much more easier with [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page).
It allows to mock not only interfaces, so. Take a look:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestFakeArgs()
{
    //Arrange
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()).WillReturn(new[] { "Your", "Fake", "Args" });

    //Act
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Your", args[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Fake", args[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Args", args[0]);
}
```

Mocking `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` took only one line:

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()).WillReturn(new[] { "Your", "Fake", "Args" });
```

And you don't need to create new Interfaces and to change production code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "Mock Everything: 15 Days Trial"

Comment: Nice) But you know, some things are worth buying. It saved me a lot of money and time in sum

Comment: I wasn't trying to suggest it wasn't necessarily worth buying for some people (although if your MSDN supports Fakes, I believe that can accomplish the same thing - at least that feature).  It was more for future readers of this question who don't necessarily have the means for whatever reason to invest in the licensing for a tool so they didn't hopefully waste their time clicking on the link.  It might be worth incorporating that information into your answer for the benefit of future readers, as well.

Comment: Also, apart from only loosely answering OP's question: [Avoid overt self-promotion.  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something unit-testable it should have its dependencies on a abstraction that is at least as strict as its implementation.

Usually you'd get the dependencies through your constructor of your class or a property method.  Constructor is preferred, generally, because now a consumer of your class knows at compile-time what dependencies are needed.

```
public void int Main(string[] args)
{
    // Validate the args are valid (not shown).

    var config = new AppConfig();
    config.Value1 = args[0];
    config.Value2 = int.Parse(args[1]);
    // etc....
}

public class MyService()
{
    private AppConfig _config;

    public MyService(AppConfig config)
    {
        this._config = config;
    }
}
```

I normally don't put a config object behind an interface because it only has data - which is serializable.  As long as it has no methods, then I shouldn't need to replace it with a subclass with `override`-d behavior.  Also I can just `new` it up directly in my tests.

Also, I've never ran into a situation when I wanted to depend on an abstraction of the command line arguments themselves to a service - why does it need to know it's behind a command-line?  The closest I've gotten is use [PowerArgs](https://github.com/adamabdelhamed/PowerArgs) for easy parsing, but I'll consume that right in `Main`.  What I normally do is something like maybe read in the port number for a web server on the command-line arguments (I let the user of the app choose so that I can run multiple copies of my web server on the same machine - maybe different versions or so I can run automated tests while I'm debugging and not conflict ports), parse them directly in my `Main` class.  Then in my web server I depend on the parsed command-line arguments, in this case an `int`.  That way the fact that the configuration is coming from a command-line is irrelevant - I can move it to an `App.config` file later (which is also basically bound to the lifecycle of the process) if I prefer - then I can extract common configuration to `configSource` files.

Instead of depending on an abstraction for command-line in general (which each service consuming would have to re-parse if you kept it pure), I usually abstract the command-line and `App.config` dependencies to a strongly-typed object - maybe an app-level config class and a test-level config class and introduce multiple configuration objects as needed - (the app wouldn't necessarily care about this, while the E2E test infrastructure would need this in a separate part of the `App.config`: where do I grab the client static files from, where do I grab the build scripts in a test or developer environment to auto-generate/auto-update an index.html file, etc.).